# Modifying a camera sensor to work with CSI-2 connector

Tags: camera

We're using Raspberry Pi's as the base of our product, and need specific camera sensors. Specifically we need, an (1) IR cut lens, (2) 130+ degree FOV, (3) 850nm IR LED lights, and a (4) compact form factor. We found camera sensors that are ideal for us, but they only come in USB version. Unfortunately, USB leads to too much CPU usage so now we're only looking for CSI-2 type cameras.

I'm trying to understand how difficult it is to ask a manufacturer to modify a USB camera to work with the Raspberry Pi CSI interface. I'd love to know:
1. What specifically do I need to tell the manufacturer about the connector? Do I say (1) it needs to work with Raspberry Pi or (2) do I list the requirements of the CSI-2 connector?
2. If the answer is (2) above, what are those requirements? Does anyone besides Raspberry Pi use the same connector?

This is an example of a perfect camera module for us, except that it's USB: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/ELP-H-264-2mp-wide-angle_60578323130.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.23.43a75cadW9bqcb

Thanks! I don't have a electrical engineering background so my apologies if these aren't the right questions to ask.

Comment: there appear to be a lot of cameras available, so it is something that is being made in quantity .... just email the manufacturer that makes the camera that you like ........https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=301102&SearchText=csi-2+camera

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to adapt your project to use USB webcams. Making custom webcams with RPi-compatible interface will require the effort which only makes sense if you'll need 10000-50000 units or more.

Comment: Unless the cameras use the same sensors as the existing pi camera modules (Omnivision OV5647 and Sony IMX219) you don't stand much chance of getting it working: the closed source camera firmware only supports these sensors and only understands their register definitions